# Previous login notification

Tags: centos, login, notifications

I am using CentOS 6. How can I configure it so the system notifies the user, upon successful login, of the date and time of the last login? Is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't ssh do that by default?

Answer (score 4):

You can the pam_lastlog module to display the date of last login upon successful logon.

You can refer to the pam_lastlog man page for more options, but to accomplish what you want just add the following to the /etc/pam.d/login file

```
session required pam_lastlog.so nowtmp
```